# Unresolved import `__client_accounts_u8`

Tags: solana-program

I am getting this error when using anchor build.

error[E0432]: unresolved import `__client_accounts_u8`

--> programs/errors/src/instructions/claim_token.rs:5:10
|
5 | #[derive(Accounts)]
|          ^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `__client_accounts_u8`

Do you have any ideas as to why this crate isn't declared?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code, else we're just guessing.